# Riak responds with 204 even if returnbody is true

Tags: riak

We are running loadtests and Riak is sometimes responding with 204 No content when we do a PUT operation, even though we've passed `returnbody=true` ([this answer](http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-July/004828.html) implies this is not expected)

It happens rarely, so what might be the possible reasons?

Our riak has 9 nodes, w=5, n_val=6, r=2.

Answer (score 0):

You will get a 204 whenever there is no data to return.  I've seen this sometimes using the PHP client when json_encode returns false, which results in the object being stored with a 0-byte value.  Since there is no data to include in the body, the server returns '204 No Content'

That is just one possible way this can occur.  I'm sure there are a multitude of situations where a key is stored with just metadata and no value.

Comment: thanks.  But we put an actual object (serialized to json), and it's visible from the logs that the content exists. And after putting actual content, riak responds with 204, which doesn't sound logical